# TLS 1.2 support in SQL Server 2014 Express Edition (12.0.2000.8)

Tags: ssl, sql

I'm trying to find out information about Microsoft SQL 2014 Express Edition ( version 12.0.2000.8). I need to know if it has support for TLS 1.2.

I'm trying different .UDL tests using SQL Native Client 11 from different servers and I fail with this error:

[image: SQL Server Native Client Error]

Does SQL Server 2014 Express Edition support TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be on SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU5 to support TLS 1.2. You can download SP2 from this link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53167

This link has a lot of detailed information that includes the supported build versions:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server